# Django - advanced search

Tags: python, django, postgresql, search

I know there are two other questions with almost the same name, but I checked them before asking this one. One asked the same question but provided no context and no good description of their goal. Another needed another type of answer, although it shared this one's name. I hope you can understand why I created a new question.

I need to apply advanced search filters to my database to search effectively. I use Django and PostgreSQL. Some things in my list of "advanced search filters":

1. In default behaviour, it's going to ignore stop words, such as "a", "the", and "is"
2. Searching for exact phrases by enclosing text in `""`
3. Since this is a website where books are uploaded, books written by a specific author
4. Books for a certain age group
5. Books in a certain genre

If I get all of these from within regular expressions, how am I supposed to search for them?

I think I can think of how to do all of these, but I just wanted to know of a way to do it without using a list of stop words and try not to consider them or something like that. Is there any feature in Django that can help me to these effectively and with relatively less effort?

Comment: Have you tried `django-filter` ?

Comment: If you are using Postgres, it may bre worth your while reviewing the docs for [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/textsearch.html)

Comment: Is there support for that in django? I really don't want to use SQL for some reason